# Unable to symlink static files using express.static() in Next js

Tags: express, next.js

I'm prototyping a NextJS implementation with the following server code:

```
import express from 'express';
import next from 'next';
import path from 'path';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

dotenv.config();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  // Custom build resources aliases
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  server.use('/favicon.ico', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static', 'images', 'icons', 'favicon.ico')));
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Custom/dynamic routes
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  server.get('/p/:id', (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/post';
    const queryParams = { title: req.params.id };
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams);
  });
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Default route
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Express: Listener
  server.listen(process.env.WEB_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port: ${process.env.WEB_PORT}...`);
  });
}).catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

As apparent, my static assets sit in a `/static/` folder. Of these, I have a favicon file at `/static/images/icons/favicon.ico`. I am able to visit this file using https://schandillia.com/static/images/icons/favicon.ico. However, when I try hitting https://schandillia.com/favicon, it throws a 404. Am I not using `express.static()` correctly?

Comment: yup, `static` mean: this dir be root for static files.  Static doc: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html, for favicon you should use:https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon. Also  https://schandillia/favicon.ico is correct request

Comment: Forget the bit that it's a favicon (for which I ought to use something like serve-favicon. Just think of the file as any image file sitting at `/static/images/icons/`. Shouldn't this file (say, some_image.png) be accessible at schandillia.com/some_image.png since I have defined `/some_image.png` as a symlink for `/static/images/icons/some_image.png`?

Comment: If you do not configure otherwise (`<meta`), the browser will look for `favicon.ico`,  not` .png` It should work: `app.get ('favicon.ico', (req, res) => {res.sendFile (...) }) `or` res.redirect ('/images/icons/some.file.png') `

Comment: But the best solution is to transfer all static file support to a real web server: nginx or apache.